# Negation of Bits

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bit, digital

The below code gives output `-1`.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() 
{
    int x=0;
    cout<<~x;
    return 0;
}
```

But when I do the following modifications the answer changes to `4294967295`.
just want to know that why in case of int it is not giving `-2147483647` which is 111.... 32 times

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
     unsigned int x=0;
    cout<<~x;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you need to learn about [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement)?

Comment: What did you expect? A `unsigned` can't hold negative numbers, so 'all bits 1' will be a large number, whereas with a `signed` it will not (hint: sign bit, two's complement).  What is your specific question?

Comment: just want to know that why in case of int it is not giving -2147483647 which is 111.... 32 times

Comment: Here it's just remember that Int has also + values (not only minus) so half of it is -, other half +. What is well explained with two's complement mentioned by SPD.

Comment: @Rahul Verma "just want to know that why in case of int it is not giving -2147483647" - as already mentioned, read up on [two's complement](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement).

Answer (score 2):

The `~` operator inverts all bits in the operand.  Here, `x` starts out as 0. So assuming an `int` is 4 bytes wide it has the following binary representation:

```
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
```

When all bits are inverted you get:

```
11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111
```

Assuming two's complement representation of integers, the value of this bit sequence is -1.  Note that if you add 1 to this value all bits become 0 (i.e. -1 + 1 = 0).

In contrast, a value of -2147483647 has the following representation:

```
10000000 00000000 00000000 00000001
```